Grid oculta mis tooltip
Mi problema es que tengo un grid con items, pero el mismo oculta los tooltip de cada uno. He probado ajustando el overflow del box, grid e item, pero sigue sin funcionar. Que les parece que pueda ser? Les dejo el codigo e imagen.
<div class="inventory-box">
    <div class="inventory-grid">
            <div class="inventory-item">
                <div class="item-details">
                    
                </div>
                <!-- Tooltip -->
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <span class="tooltiptext">
                        ..contenido..
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

El css donde quite las opciones de colores, radios y demas:
    .inventory-box {
    overflow: visible;
    width: fit-content;
    height: auto;
}

.inventory-grid {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    overflow: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.inventory-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

.inventory-item {
    height: 50px;
}

/* Tooltip*/
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    position: absolute; 
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%; 
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    z-index: 9999; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap
}

/* Pequeña punta del tooltip */
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.inventory-item:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

Del codigo css quite las opciones visuales para que puedan leerlo mas comodamente. Aqui las imagenes con el problema en cuestion:


Me pide mas texto para poder publicar la pregunta, pero no se que mas puedo aclarar. El comentare que estoy realizando un juego rpg sin gameplay, y que la parte que mas dolores de cabeza me esta dando (porque no me gusta) es el frontend. Me encantaria poder tener dinero para pagarle a un disenador que lidie con todos estos problemas. Relamente un dolor de cabeza. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

"Me encantaria poder tener dinero para pagarle a un disenador que lidie con todos estos problemas" -> Un diseñador hace el diseño, no la implementación... de todas maneras, por qué pones overflow: visible; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;??? No tiene sentido que primero uses el shorthand para poner ambos en visible y luego especifiques ambos a hidden. Si les pones hidden, obviamente no vas a ver nada que desborde.... Te recomiendo proporcionar un [mre] usando un fragmento de JS para este tipo de preguntas. Es imposible saber qué está pasando realmente solo viendo trozos de código.

Gracias Benito! no sabia lo de overflow X e Y. Y ejemplo ya lo habia simplificado

Está simplificado pero no es FUNCIONAL. Si no podemos ejecutarlo, cómo vamos a verlo?? Puedes crear un snippet aquí mismo en la página y que lo podamos ejecutar y modificar directamente aquí. Es la mejor manera de obtener ayuda. Si no es un coñazo tener que montar algo solo para que mi código no reproduzca tu problema...
